# Compact surface on which isometries act transitively

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, isometry

Let $M$ be a smooth orientable closed compact $2$-manifold equipped with a Riemannian metric such that its group of isometries acts on it transitively.

What examples are there of such $M$ except the sphere? Is there a classification of such manifolds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The torus $T^2$ endowed with the flat metric.

Comment: Is there a classification of such manifolds?

Comment: I believe that if the curvature of the metric is constant, you have just the sphere and and the 2-dimensional torus, since the group of automorphisms of a riemannian surface whose curvature is negative is finite.

Comment: Isometries act transitively implies that curvature is constant, right? So that should complete the 2d classification.

Comment: Almost! You also need the projective plane. Up to diffeomorphism there are exactly three compact surfaces on which isometries act transitively. The torus, the sphere and the projective plane.